# Android App which not removes even after System reset

Tags: java, android

How can I develop app which should not remove even after factory reset. Is there any way to doing that?

Comment: Why every one downvote this question?

Comment: Your question is very broad and shows that you have not attempted to find the answer for yourself.

Comment: I tried to findout but no luck.

Comment: if you have a rooted device, push your app to /system/priv-app folder and reboot.

Comment: @ManuuJain: your question is valid and i support it as this scenareo every developer does not faces in everyday coding. accept my answer if it works for you.

Comment: @Mannu : I am eager to know if my solution is working for you??

Comment: Ya your solution is working for me but Artion solution is much better than yours.

Comment: @mannu : thanks, i just wanted to know its is working for you or not. As someone has simply downvoted my answer saying its incorrect. :(

Comment: Some mad guys who don't have guts to give answer they do downvote.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When factory reset occurs, it deletes all user apps and preferences but leaves all system apps. When there is an update of the rom, it writes the system partition, having root privileges. So there are two possibilities: with root privileges, install the app as a system app or build the rom with the app included. In both cases you have to get informed what this implies in building the app because system apps have some differences from normal (user) apps.

Answer (score 0):

It is only possible for application build in android ROM. For example CyanogenMod rom collects set of prebuilded application and they always be in you telephone even after factory reset

Answer (score -1):

You need to have root permission for that I guess.
If you have a rooted test device, push your app to /system/priv-app folder and reboot.

Comment: suppose if any user have root permission then how can I achieve this?

Comment: this is wrong, on a factory reset, everything will be deleted, also root access. Factory reset means, the original software shipped with the device will be installed....

Comment: @Opiatefuchs: are you really so sure if you install the app in /system-priv app and then do a factory rest it will go??
or if I remove a app from /system/priv-app then will it come back on factory rest???

Comment: @Opiatefuchs : can you plase explain the reason for downvote??
this solution is already accepted.

Comment: I am not the downvoter. The reason why You get downvoted is maybe, that only moving an app to the system folder will not work. There are some things more to make a system app. But don´t care about, there are a few poeple here who just downvoting without giving a reason....

Comment: @Opiatefuchs: thanks for response. Manny has aready tested this and its working fine for him he confirmed in above comments. I dont know why some people downvote/upvote so randomly showing immaturity. :(

Comment: sometimes I have the presumption that it is a sport for some embittered poeple... :)